# Everything wrong with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, internet, startup, windows-10

I was a Windows10 user and, as I wanted to move to linux, I rencently changed to Ubuntu 16.04 . I really like the looks of Ubuntu, however, when comparing it with Windows10, Ubuntu:

- boost is a lot slower (shut down is faster though);
- internet connection/download velocity is slower (same connection);
- battery levels drop faster
- can't change to nvidia videocard instead of intel.

pc specs:

- 6gb ram;
- Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4 ;
- Intel® Ivybridge Mobile ;

How can i make it better than windows10?

Comment: This is too broad.

Comment: Too broad? Ubuntu is lighter than Windows10 so in the same computer it should run faster than windows! I would like to know why ubuntu is slower and how too solve it.. not too broad i think...

Comment: You mentioned a number of not related issues. They can't be resolved in one answer. And how you measured "slowness" except boot time? You can ask separate questions or find answers how to fix each problem. The first issue is that you did not install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Have you installed first time updates on your new Ubuntu? Do that and restart. Let us know specific questions you have after that.

Comment: I have installed nvidia drivers already but in Nvidia X Server Settings there is no option to make the change..

Comment: There are lot's of answers related to this. You need to disable Secure Boot. Each issue has its own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, working with Linux including Ubuntu can be ridiculously easy or ridiculously tough, dependent of the given hardware you use...

Just give it a chance and try to figure out what is disturbing you and how to solve it, like searching for answers and asking **specific** questions, for example in this forum.

Nobody can give you a general solution how to make Ubuntu better than Windows, this is relative anyway!

In Linux you have practically no limits in terms of system manipulation and configuration, you just need to know how and where to change the stuff. This task is a long and very interesting journey since you are new in Linux. You need patience and a will to discover a whole new world in terms of computing.

---

*First* - open the Terminal - `CTRL` + `ALT` + `T` - and type the following three commands to bring your system up-to-date:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Good possible that a few little problems you face will disappear after the update.

---

*Second* - again in Terminal, clean up your system:

Remove unneeded packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Get rid of partial packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Get rid of 'orphaned' packages: you may have to install deborphan first

```
sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge
```

Remove configuration files of uninstalled packages:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

Clean out unused package stuff (cache):

```
sudo apt-get clean
```